# CKQueryOperation got error "No operations present in request" randomly

Tags: ios, objective-c, cloudkit, ckqueryoperation, ckerror

I'm trying to fetch some records from Cloud Server w/ the code snippet below. It returns records w/o any error in most times:

```
CKQuery * query = [[CKQuery alloc] initWithRecordType:@"MyTable"
                                            predicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"accountID = 1"]];
CKQueryOperation * recordFetchOperation = [[CKQueryOperation alloc] initWithQuery:query];
recordFetchOperation.database = [[CKContainer defaultContainer] privateCloudDatabase];
recordFetchOperation.recordFetchedBlock = ^(CKRecord *record) {
  // get records succeed some times
};
recordFetchOperation.queryCompletionBlock = ^(CKQueryCursor *cursor, NSError *operationError) {
  if (operationError) [self _handleError:operationError];
};

... // some other operations

NSOperationQueue * queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[queue addOperations:@[recordFetchOperation, ...]
   waitUntilFinished:NO];
```

But sometimes, it returns error:

> {
>     NSDebugDescription = "CKInternalErrorDomain: 1009";
>     NSLocalizedDescription = "No operations present in request";
>     NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=CKInternalErrorDomain Code=1009 \"No operations present in request\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No operations present in request}";
>   }

I've checked the error code, it's `CKErrorInvalidArguments`, which as doc said

> Bad client request (bad record graph, malformed predicate)

I've no idea how this error comes and how to handle this error, unlike `CKErrorNetworkUnavailable` error, it does not have `CKErrorRetryAfterKey` value in `error.userInfo` for me to send the request after a time interval.

---

<strike>Btw, when I got this error, all my operations will have this error w/o any record returned.</strike>

Comment: In a case like this I would retry the operation after 2 or 3 seconds. See if that helps.

Comment: @rmaddy yeah, i do so temporary now. Searched a lot places but cannot find any answer about this weird error, just sent a TSI to apple support team for help.

Comment: Update: After discussing two days, they've no idea about it as well. And i've received another reply this morning (05:11 CST+8000), which suggests me to submit a bug report. Just did now.

Comment: @Kjuly Hi, did you get any solution for that?

Comment: @MaheshPrasadMahalik i just retry the operation after a time internal as a solution, if it keeps fail because of this error, just cancel it. For now, the bug ticket is still open (https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=26153873). ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯